# What is an acceptable production deployment for a web app that may have slight configuration differences between instances on different servers

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, production, dev-to-production

So right now we are using Git as our version control. We also use docker compose to manage the deployment

I want to handle the fact that we have some customers that want their own version of the site with slight docker-compose.yml differences (such as an environment variable defined by docker). This causes the git pull to worry about the uncommitted changes in the docker-compose.yml file.

I'm thinking that I can open a branch from master and then pull changes from master as time goes on so that we don't need to worry about the changes for config specific files.

Of course I can be completely missing something and there exists an easy solution to all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard git way is creating a branch and keeping it updated frequently from master. This is a very common approach.

In fact most open source projects use a very similar technique whereby a fork is taken from the main repository and custom changes by a contributer are done on the forked repository.

As a small remark, it is better to maintain the environment variable in a env_file since env values will likely be different from the client. That way you would have less manual merges in the docker-compose file.

**Update**

Another idea that might be worth evaluating, is [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Basically, you can put the stuff that need to be different into a git submodule, and keep the parent module the same between your repo and the client's repo. That way the client points to his own submodule and there is no need to maintainer separate branches.

Comment: So the thing is I want the feature branches to be off of master and then a branch for a specific company who wants there own server lets say customer-2. So would i just create a branch (not sure if bitbucket uses forks) for the customer-2 and merge the master branch into the new branch when changes come in from other feature branches

Comment: Yes. Ideally, the master branch should contain the defaults that allow you to start everything. Other branches should contain the customer specifics that are not supposed to be merged back to the master. So customer branches pull changes from the master branch and not the other way around.

Comment: @TimmyZubkisSearcy I updated the answer. Git submodules might provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

We are using this simple approach:
we have single repository contains all configurations for all instances. Our directory structure is:

```
/base
   docke-compose.yml
   .env
/test
   docker-compose.override.yml
   .env
/production
    docker-compose.override.yml
   .env
```

It allows us to not duplicate some basics things in every `docker-compose.yml` Also it allows us to use `git branches` for some new features/bugfixes.

Comment: So the thing is that we need multiple production servers. So should I branch a version for lets say... customer-2